# Output results to a SQL table

Tags: powershell

I have the following code which returns what I need but I am struggling to output this to a table from which I can further query.

```
$instances =  invoke-sqlcmd –ServerInstance "myserver" –Database "my db" –query "select instanceconnectname from [dbo].[smytable] WHERE InstanceConnectName LIKE '%CLU%' and connect = 1"
Write-Host $instances.instanceconnectname
foreach ($svr in $instances.instanceconnectname){
    $dt = new-object "System.Data.DataTable"
    $cn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection "server=$svr;database=master;Integrated Security=sspi"
    $cn.Open()
    $sql = $cn.CreateCommand()
    $sql.CommandText = "SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS ServerName, SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS') As ActiveNode"
    $rdr = $sql.ExecuteReader()
    $dt.Load($rdr)
    $cn.Close()
    $dt | Format-Table -autosize
}
```

I have been reading about some custom functions out there is that the only way to do this really?  I had thought I could just do some kind of SQL Insert but not figured out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of outputting to a DataTable, I would output to a DataSet, which you can then further query. e.g.:

```
$cn = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection "server=$svr;database=master;Integrated Security=sspi"

#Create the SQL Command from a connection string
$SqlCmd = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$SqlCmd.CommandText = "SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS ServerName, SERVERPROPERTY('ComputerNamePhysicalNetBIOS') As ActiveNode"
$SqlCmd.Connection = $cn

#Create the SQL DataAdapter
$SqlAdapter = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
$SqlAdapter.SelectCommand = $SqlCmd

#Fill the DataSet
$DataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
$SqlAdapter.Fill($DataSet)
```

Now with it in a DataSet, you can query it, like this:

```
$DataSet.tables[0].select("ServerName like 'Bob%'")
```

Hopefully that is enough to get you started...